# Checking approximation of E

Tags: math, wolfram-mathematica

MathWorld [page](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/eApproximations.html) gives a simple numeric formula for `e` that's allegedly correct for first 10^25 digits. It states that `e` is approximately

```
(1 + 9^-4^(7*6))^3^2^85
```

Any idea how to check whether this formula is correct even for the first 10 digits?
Here's another way of writing the right hand side

```
Power[Plus[1, Power[9, Times[-1, Power[4, Times[7, 6]]]]], Power[3, Power[2, 85]]]
```

Comment: You might get better answers with http://math.stackexchange.com/

Comment: A similar question was answered here earlier -- http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4696882/solving-power-towers

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This problem does not need Mathematica at all. First, it is easy to show that `9^(4^(7*6))` is exactly equal to `3^2^85`, since

```
 9^(4^(7*6)) = 3^(2*4^(7*6)) = 3^(2^(1+2*(7*6))) = 3^2^85
```

Then, we know that one of the ways to represent `e` is as a limit

```
e = lim (1+1/n)^n, n->infinity
```

The only question is what is the error given that `n` is very large but finite. We have

```
(1+1/n)^n = e^log((1+1/n)^n) = e^(n*log(1+1/n)) = e^(1-1/(2n)+O(1/n^2)) = e + O(1/n),
```

Given the `n = 3^2^85`, i we take the `log(10,n) = 2^85 log(10,3) ~ 1.85 *10^25`, we get an estimate
similar to the quoted one

Answer (score 1):

Repeatedly taking logs is a nice (usually) generally-applicable solution to problems of this sort. Here's a more special-case approach to this problem: recall that e = lim(n->infinity, (1+1/n)^n).  So to be a good approximation to e, all we need is for 9^(4^(42)) (the denominator of the fractional part) to be sufficiently close to 3^(2^85) and big.

In this case, they're identical, so we have n=3^(2^85), and it's going to be a *very* good approximation to e.  These are big numbers, but not unworkably so:

```
>>> from mpmath import *
>>> iv.dps = 50 # let's use interval arithmetic, just for fun
>>> x = mpi(9)**(-(4**(42)))
>>> up = (mpi(3)**(2**85))
>>> x
mpi('1.4846305545498656772753385085652043615636250118238876e-18457734525360901453873570', 
'1.4846305545498656772753385085652043615636250118238899e-18457734525360901453873570')
>>> 1/x
mpi('6.7356824695231749871315222528985858700759934154677854e+18457734525360901453873569', 
'6.7356824695231749871315222528985858700759934154678156e+18457734525360901453873569')
>>> up
mpi('6.7356824695231749871315222528985858700759934154678005e+18457734525360901453873569', 
'6.7356824695231749871315222528985858700759934154678156e+18457734525360901453873569')
>>> 0 in (1/x-up)
True
```

Working out the exact error bounds on e is left as an exercise for the reader ;-) -- hint: compare the number of digits of accuracy the mathworld page claims and the above numbers, and ask why that might be, thinking of the series of approximations (1+1/1)^1, (1+1/2)^2, etc.

Comment: I don't get how this prove the correctness of the first 10^25 digits. Unless that is what you "left as an exercise" ... but this is not homework (I guess), so you should try to answer the question

Comment: The full argument was given above by Leonid Shifrin while I was sleeping :^) -- as I noted, the series of approximations (1+1/n)^n as n->infinity converges to e.  The dominant error is of order 1/n (that's the fact which one can notice and then easily prove after you see that the exponents listed above 18457734525360901453873569, are so close to the claimed number of correct digits 18457734525360901453873570, which can't be a coincidence.)